# Cannot access entire content of file using Uri provided by Photo Picker(Android)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, base64

I am trying to parse the file that corresponds to the Uri that I recieve from the Photo Picker intent

I tried making an InputStream as many people suggested on other questions, but it seems like it only parses one part of the file.  I need the file in base64 format because I send it to an API. For example, this my code:

This is the part where I get the Uri from the viewModel and try to read from the file:

```
val fileContents =  fileInputStream?.readAllBytes()
val base64encodedPhoto = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContents)
println(base64encodedPhoto)
fileInputStream?.close()
```

When I log the result image encoded, this is what I get(encoded photo):

```
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
```

By decoding it with a tool online, it amounts only to a quarter of the picture, so this:

[image]

Instead, it should have looked like this:

[image]

May you help me? Thanks so much <3.

Comment: Logcat doesn't show the full length of the log.

Comment: Ment to say is: Log.d() or println() does not print the whole sting if the string is very long.

Comment: You better save that base64 encoded string to file. Then use the file.

Comment: `need the file in base64 format because I send it to an API.` Bad api as with base64 encoding you need to transfer 30% more bytes. Try to change the server script to accept the file itself.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks so much for the tip! I will do that <3.